# Solr - Difference in behavior for 'q' and 'df' queries

Tags: solr

I am trying to understand why there is a difference in the following behaviors when searching using 'q' and 'df'. In my understanding, if 'q' is not specified, it will default to 'df'.

**Example**
Aim of search is to look for 'Workout plans' in 'title' field of documents.

**Search method #1**
http://localhost:8983/solr/workoutstuff/select?q=title:Workout%20Plans&wt=json

**Search method #2**
http://localhost:8983/solr/workoutstuff/select?df=title&q=Workout%20Plans&wt=json

**Results**

There are results in Search Method #1 but no results in Search Method #2.

I would like to understand why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a **df**, there will still probably be a default search field, probably the field **text**.(Depending on your configuration).

So for search method 1: The term *Workout* is searched for in the **title** field the word *Plans* is searched against the default field (probably **text**) because there are no quotes around the **title** expression.
e.g. title:"Workout Plans"

Search method 2: Searches for *Workout* OR *Plans* in the default field, **title**. Again because there are no quotes.(Assuming the default operator is OR)

So your two search methods should return the same results if you put quotes around the search value.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks